# How to change default database from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have installed SQL Server 2005 Express with/on the time I installed some software few months ago, but then, I just install SQL Server 2008 Standard..

My question is why I run SQL Server Management Studio 2008, connected server is the SQL Server 2005 Express (9.0.5000) why does it not connect to the 2008 database?

I have been tried close ssms, in the servername field I entered localhost, but result is same. ssms 2008 and 2005 express database..

Why? How come?? How to fix it I mean change the default database to 2008

I think LOCALHOST or the server computer name is already default set to database 2005 express, is above I said, I installed 2005 express first then 2008 standard in a same server.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I have been tried, close ssms, in the servername i type localhost, but result is same. ssms2008 and 2005 database..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me when I start up SSMS it pops up the connection to the server last accessed, just type in the IP/Servername from the 2008 Server..connect. Close SSMS, open it again and it should display the 2008 server from now on. You can also add the server to the registered server group of course (CTRL + ALT + G)

based on your comment

why would you type localhost..is the 2008 install a default or a named instance? if it is a named instance you need `localhost\Instancename`  Where Instancename is the name you gave the 2008 instance when you installed it

Comment: I have been tried, close ssms, in the servername i type localhost, but result is same. ssms2008 and 2005 database...

Comment: okay, is like this.. i installed 2005 express on Feb, but just installed 2008 standard this week... also i can't uninstall/remove 2005 because 1 application is using 2005 express.

Answer (score -1):

FOr the first time the SQL Server management Studio will use the settings from SQL2005, you can change as referred above.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.